# Close Keyboard on IPhone Simulator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a login page that places the username above the password then the login button last on the bottom. When I type the username, the keyboard covers the pass and login. How do I friggin close the keyboard when someone clicks outside of the text fields or is there a way to generate a close keyboard button? The only ways I have found how to do it is to programmatically add fields to the UI. Is there a way to accomplish this using the editor?

Here is my header file:

```
@interface Login : UIViewController{
RootViewController *rootViewController;
IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *usernameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *loginButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender;

@end
```

The only way I found to do it was something like:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
[textField resignFirstResponder]; 
return YES; 
} 
- (void)loadView 
{ 
self.view = contentView; 
[contentView release]; 
// Create a field with a Done return key 
usernameField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0f, 40.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f)] retain]; 
[usernameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect]; 
usernameField.placeholder = @"name"; 
usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; 
usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
usernameField.delegate = self; 
[contentView addSubview:usernameField]; 
[usernameField release]; 
}
```

Which programs the view and adds fields.Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this in a number of ways.  One way would be to slide the view containing your fields and button up when the keyboard becomes active by adjusting the frame top.  Look at UITextFieldDelegate. If the text fields are in a table view then you can shrink the height of the table view.

If you want to hide the keyboard when a user taps outside the text field, you can add a UIGestureRecognizer to the view.  When a tap is detected you can tell the active text field to resignFirstResponder.

Comment: The problem with the gesture recognizer on the view is that it applies to the subviews as well, meaning that tapping a field will invoke the gesture recognizer and the keyboard will never appear. Although, it is possible to do hit testing to determine what kind of view has been tapped and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Looking at some older code, I used a UITapGestureRecognizer.  I set the property cancelsTouchesInView = NO.  My tap handler basically resizes the view to fill the space taken by the keyboard.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were talking about using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to resign first responder.

Comment: I just added a resignFirstResponder to the main file and pointed the textfield to files owner. The keyboard hides when hitting enter. So many complicated explanations everywhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to listen for the `UIKeyboard` notifications and resize your view appropriately so the entire form is visible when the keyboard appears. From there you can wire up the return button on the keyboard to take an appropriate action depending on which text field has first responder status. For instance, pressing return from the username field will tab to the password field and pressing it from the password field would be equivalent to tapping the login button. No need to manually manage the keyboard.

Comment: +1 for a better solution than requiring the user to dismiss the keyboard to view what they need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have an inputAccessoryView for the UITextField with a "Done" button, that resigns the keyboard when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything on a scroll view, and when the keyboard is firstresponder then add the height of the keyboard to the height of the scroll view.  Do the inverse when the keyboard disappears.